# Prolog foreach : display facts

Tags: prolog

In prolog, I want to display simple facts like this  :

```
person(Mike, 18).
person(Alice, 22).
person(Louis, 34).
```

in this :

```
------------------
| Name     | Age |
------------------
| Mike     | 18  |
| Alice    | 22  |
| Louis    | 34  |
------------------
```

I test with my code, but seems dont work :

```
print:-
 forall(person(N, A), writeln("| ", N, "     | ", A, "  |")).
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: How exactly does it not work?

Comment: Identifiers that start with a capital letter are variables. So facts such as `person(Mike, 18).` express that anyone is of the age of 18 (since `Mike` is a variable).

Comment: Adding onto what @lurker says, you can quote uppercase atoms: `person('Mike', 18).`